# Meromorphic function written as a quotient of entire functions with real Taylor series coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a meromorphic function on $\mathbb C$ with $f(z)\in \mathbb R$ for all $z\in \mathbb R$, except possibly at the poles of $f$. Show that there exists  entire functions $$g(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i z^i \quad\text{and}\quad h(z)= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} b_i z^i ,$$ such that $f(z)=g(z)/h(z)$, and $a_i,b_i\in \mathbb R$ for all $i$.

I know from the Weierstrass factorization theorem that there are entire functions $g,h$ such that $f=g/h$. I also know that if $f(z) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i z^i$ is an entire function with $f(z)\in \mathbb R$ for every $z\in \mathbb R$, then $a_i\in \mathbb R$ for all $i$. Thus, it remains to show that $g$ and $h$ maps the real line to itself. But this seems impossible to show. Perhaps I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can give a proof using Weierstrass factors but we can give a direct proof from your observation that $f(z)=g(z)/h(z)$, $g,h$ entire; it is obvious that $g,h$ have real Taylor coefficients (at zero) iff they preserve the real axis since $n!a_n=g^n(0)$ and one can take all the derivatives at zero (or any real for that matter) to be the usual real ones of the restriction $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ if $g$ preserves the real axis

We can assume $g,h$ have no common zeroes as we factor them out, so the zeroes of $g$ are the zeroes of $f$ and the zeroes of $h$ are the poles of $f$. The hypothesis implies that all non-real such come in conjugate pairs with same multiplicities for both $g,h$ respectively.

Let $g^*(z)=\bar {g(\bar z)}$ the conjugate entire functions of $g$ (note that $g$ preserves the real axis iff $g=g^*$ since then they coincide on the real axis hence everywhere) and $h^*$ same for $h$; the above observation implies that $g^*$ has same zeroes with same multiplicities as $g$, same for $h^*,h$ and obviously $G(z)=g(z)g^*(z)$ preserves the reals since if $z=x$ real, $G(x)=g(x)\bar g(x)=|g(x)|^2$, while all its zeroes occur with even multipicities, same for $H$. Also since $G,H$ are not identical zero, there is $G(a)=a_1>0, H(b)=b_1>0$ for some real values $a,b$.

Since $G,H$ have all zeroes with even multiplicity, both have unique entire square roots $G_1,H_1$ determined by the condition $G_1(a)=\sqrt a_1>0, H_1(b)=\sqrt b_1>0$. If $x$ real,  $G_1(x)$ is a square root of the non-negative number $|g(x)|^2$ (could be plus or minus, do not know apriori of course except for $a$ by choice), so it is real, and same with $H_1$, so $G_1,H_1$ preserve the real axis, so they have real Taylor coefficients at zero.

But since $f^*=f$ it follows that $f^2=\frac{G}{H}$, so $f(z)=\pm\frac{G_1(z)}{H_1(z)}$ and for each non-zero, non-pole of $f$, the sign $\pm$ is preserved in a small neighborhood. This means it is locally constant outside the poles and zeroes of $f$, and since those are isolated, it is constant everywhere, so indeed $f(z)=c\frac{G_1(z)}{H_1(z)}$ for $c$ fixed $\pm 1$. Done!

Comment: Will the infinite product made up of the "common factors" of $g,h$ be a convergent infinite product?

Comment: @GEdgar - indeed one may need to factor out Weirstrass factors if $g,h$ have infinite zeroes in common, but the theorem that any meromorphic function is a quotient of entire functions comes with the corollary that those can be assumed to have no common factors from the proof, so if you want we can just assume that as part of the hypothesis - the OP question is essentially given such a quotient, how can one make the denominator and numerator have real coefficients, if the quotient has them, not to prove that the quotient exists

Comment: @GEdgar also one can give an algebraic topology like proof to the $f=\frac{g}{h}$ with $g,h$ "prime" - no common zeroes -without actually using Weierstrass factors, by noticing that locally one always has a prime such ratio with entire functions factors since locally there are only finitely many zeroes and poles and one can write it by hand, and then stitch them together by an analyitc continuation argument